# NodeJS Firebase App crash on Invalid JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is my NodeJS application. I've commented out some parts to narrow down the issue.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
// const path = require('path');
// const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
// const gameAPI = require('./routes/apiv1');
const startTime = Date.now();

Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;
console.log("Server Started");

// app.use('/node_modules',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')));
// app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(500).send();
});

// app.use('/v1.0', gameAPI);

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.send(`App started ${(Date.now() - startTime)/1000}s ago`);
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

when I send an invalid JSON

```
{
    "ign":"XX"
    "allies": "5"
}
```

The application crash.

```
[11:21:31]{}firebase-test:sulochana$ firebase serve --only functions,hosting
✔  functions: Using node@8 from host.
✔  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
i  functions: Watching "/home/sulochana/Documents/firebase-test/functions" for Cloud Functions...
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: public
✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
>  Server Started
✔  functions[app]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5001/scrim-engine/us-central1/app).
[hosting] Rewriting /v1.0/dota/queue to http://localhost:5001/scrim-engine/us-central1/app for local Function app
>  Server Started
i  functions: Beginning execution of "app"
>  SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 15
>      at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
>      at parse (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:89:19)
>      at /usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
>      at invokeCallback (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
>      at done (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
>      at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/usr/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
>      at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
>      at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
>      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
>      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
```

How to handle this exception. This will allow external users to crash the application

Comment: How exactly are you sending this JSON?  Please edit the question to be specific about what your client is doing, and any code that goes along with it.  You could be doing something wrong on either the client or the backend.  Ideally we should have everything necessary in the question itself to reproduce the issue.

Comment: add a try catch when parsing the client json request

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm sending this via postman. Whatever the client do, the app should not crash.

Comment: What are you really concerned about?  If someone sends invalid JSON, does something stop working the way you expect?  What specific problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: If someone sends an invalid JSON, it will cause the server to restart. This server is not stateless

Comment: why don't you try parse json in try&catch statement and catch the issue?

Comment: According to the stack trace it seems to crash before it reaches my code

Comment: How exactly are you observing that Cloud Functions restarts in a way that's problematic?  Since CF is the thing that's parsing the JSON, there's not a whole lot you can do.  But please be specific about the issue so we can learn what's wrong.

Comment: Note that the emulator you're using behaves differently than the real product.

Answer (score 1):

You have to determine where the `JSON.parse()` method is being invoked and then precede it with a test for whether the JSON is valid *before* trying to use the parsed output. For example:

```
const isValidJson = jsonString => {
  try {
    JSON.parse(jsonString)
    return true
  } catch(err) {
    return false
  }
}

if (isValidJson(jsonString)) JSON.parse(jsonString)
```

The likeliest culprit for where this parsing is happening appears to be in your game API, since it seems to be handling your app's routes.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer, you need to validate the input data before the process.

**Validate JSON**

```js
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
```

**Restart Server On Unexpected Crashes**

And also, You can use some packages like [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever), to restart your server automatically when it crash..